# sum worked hours per month in multiple years google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, yearmonth

I have a sheet where each day the working hours are noted for every employee
in top row, are dates .

i want to sum worked hours every month of a year between 2 dates and get an array/employee

i want to get an array that sums the worked hours for sept 23 and oct 23 for an employee, dynamically

{sum (sept23 worked hrs);sum(oct23 worked hrs);...}

I am trying to work with this formula, in a smaller data area, b1:d3 around but I'm missing something

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(MONTH(B1:D1&1), QUERY(B1:D3, "select month(row1),sum(row2) group by month(row1)"), 2, false)))`

[test page](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qvRB3kk21rUeOnLIVujb5lxXlTxO7TswrREnhw9SkYU/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Here's one approach you may test out:*

```js
=let(Λ,unique(filter(text(B1:1,"mmm-yy"),B1:1<>""),1), 
     vstack(hstack(,Λ),hstack(A2:A3,byrow(B2:3,lambda(Σ,index(sumif(text(B1:1,"mmm-yy"),Λ,Σ)))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have an idea as how to get around "The argument must be a range" error when the arrays are substituted with **LET** variables? I have both the B1:1 and b2:2 ranges imported as vectors from outer files, with **IMPORTRANGE()**  in a bigger **LET** function and it seems like the lambda-part of your solution, the equivalent of b1:1 range is not happy with the vector I'm trying to substitute it with. Code is something like this:` =let(dateInterval;

Comment: '=let(dateInterval, importrange(link, "oneRowRange"), workHrsMonthly, importrange(link,"oneRowRange"), Λ, unique(filter(text(dateInterval,"mmm-yy"), dateInterval<>""),1), hstack(byrow(workHrsMonthly,LAMBDA(Σ,index(sumif(text(dateInterval; "mmm-yy"),Λ,Σ)))))'

Comment: do you have a clue on what am i missing?

Comment: actually dateInterval from above formula is not an **IMPORTRANGE()** but an arrayformula between two dates: `ARRAYFORMULA(transpose(QUERY(FLATTEN(IF(DAYS(E8;D8+1)>=SEQUENCE(1;E8-D8;0);D8+1+SEQUENCE(1;E8-D8;0);""));"where Col1 is not null")))`